# Agent to forward Lotus Notes emails without human interaction

Tags: email, lotusscript

I am pretty close to being able to forward documents from lotus notes. I have an almost working script but am missing something. I see some notes on setting MailOptions or SaveOptions but I can not get it to work for what I think is a NotesUIDocument. I get either
[image: Save Document] or
[image]
by removing or adding the Call uiForward.Save. The NotesUIDocument does not seem to take arguments and I don't see how to modify any of the options in a UIdocument.  What incantation will tell notes to just close or discard the forwarded UIdocument?

I simplified the script to remove the loop. It will just send the first note in the test folder.

```
Sub Initialize
    
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim sendTo As String
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim uiDoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim uiForward As NotesUIDocument
    
    ' address to send emails to
    sendTo$ = "valid@email.address"
    
    ' get current database
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    
    ' Get list of documents in test folder
    Set view = db.GetView("Test")
    
    ' get first document
    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
    
    ' Open the email for read only in the Notes UI
    Set uiDoc = ws.EditDocument(False, doc)
    
    ' Forward the email, creating a new document in the UI
    uiDoc.Forward
    
    ' Get the new document to be forwarded
    Set uiForward = ws.CurrentDocument          
    
    ' Enter To email address(es) (comma-separated)
    uiForward.GoToField "To"
    uiForward.InsertText sendTo         
    
    ' close original document, not needed at this point
    uiDoc.Close(True)
    
    ' Send and close the forwarded document - the email is put in the Sent folder
    uiForward.Send
    
    ' Save the forwarded document
    ' This prevents the save dialog but then gets a different discard, send only, save only, cancel, save & send dialing
    Call uiForward.Save
    
    ' Close the forwarded note
    uiForward.Close(True)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that there's a standard option in the Address Book for forwarding all incoming mails to some address?

A NotesUIDocument is a foreground object, but you don't really have to use these objects. I gather that you're trying to "forward" specific mails to some destination address. May I suggest the following approach (LotusScript sort-of):

```
Set doc= view.GetFirstDocument
Set newdoc= doc.CopyToDatabase(doc.ParentDatabase)
Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", "some@address.xyz") 
Call newdoc.Send(False)
Call newdoc.Save(True, False) ' if you want to save the document
```

---

Update, 2nd option

This will create a new mail, and add the content of the original mail. I have no idea if the new mail will resemble the original mail. Furthermore, check thoroughly if attachments are copied...

```
Set doc= view.GetFirstDocument
Set newdoc= New NotesDocument(doc.ParentDatabase)
Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", "some@address.xyz") 
Dim body As New NotesRichTextItem(newdoc, "Body")
' you could add lines to body here, like
'   Call body.AppendText("Mailed: " + Format$(doc.PostedDate(0))
'   Call body.AddNewline(1)
Call body.AppendRTItem(doc.GetFirstItem("Body"))
Call newdoc.Send(False)
Call newdoc.Save(True, False) ' if you want to save the document
```

See the LotusScript documentation: https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/LSAZ_CHAPTER_2CREATING_COMPILING_AND_DEBUGGING_SCRIPTS.html

Comment: Thanks @D.Bugger! I started with the doc.send but I loose the context of who sent the original note and when it was received. Is there a way to emulate forwarding with the doc.send?

Comment: If anyone uses this you have to also remove the cc and bcc addresses from the original note or they will also get the email.

Comment: That's correct, you'll have to remove the fields CopyTo and BlindCopyTo. About losing context: that's true as well. If you use the back-end classes you'll have to do more things yourself. Mine was a quick hack to forward a message. If you intend to create and send a real mail you'd have to go about it differently. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much the hints and tips helped so much!